# Подключение в Unity3D (С#) неуправляемой библиотеки

Tags: c#, unity3d, native, pinvoke

Пытаюсь в приложении на C# Unity3D вызвать функции из неуправляемой библиотеки. Добавил ее в Assets, со следующими настройками 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В коде объявляю их с помощью PInvoke, вроде

```
[DllImport("avcodec-58.dll"), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
public static extern int avcodec_close(AVCodecContext pAVCodecContext);
```

Но при обращении к ним выдается ошибка "DllNotFoundException: avcodec-58.dll". Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно подключить?

---

Сделал так:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.FastCall)]     
[ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.Process)]
public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string libFilename);

public NativeMethods()
{
    IntPtr lib = LoadLibrary("Полный путь к avcodec-58.dll");
    if (lib == IntPtr.Zero)
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
}
```

Но при вызове LoadLibrary все равно выдает ошибку "Не найден указанный модуль".

Answer (score 1):

игрушка компилируется конкретно Юнити. Не вижуалкою и не MonoDevelop. Это значит что все что нужно для подключения внешней DLL — просто поместить в Assets папку. Дальше юнити синхронизирует эти изменения с проектом — добавит нужные референсы на библиотеку в проект.

Нужно иметь в виду, что сама DLL должна быть скомпилирована под .NET 3.5 или ниже т.к. юнити работает именно с 3.5.

Так же есть оф. документация по теме: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Plugins.html

Comment: avcodec-58.dll является частью библиотеки FFmpeg, она, вообще, разве компилируется под .NET? Технология PInvoke как раз ведь и позволяет использовать библиотеки, написанные на C/C++ в C#. Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: Если это не родная .Net библиотек тогда дожен быть полезен ответ отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923595/how-to-use-a-c-dll-in-unity3d